# WPF custom control size override

Tags: wpf, controls, size

I'm creating a custom WPF control which derives from Grid.
It's a Chess board and so I want it's width to be the same as it's height.
How can I accomplish this?

Edit:

I tried the following.

```
private void cbcBoard_SizeChanged(object sender, SizeChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.NewSize.Width != e.NewSize.Height)
        {
            double m = Math.Min(e.NewSize.Width, e.NewSize.Height);

            cbcBoard.Width = m;
            cbcBoard.Height = m;
        }
    }
```

It didn't work. Any ideas?

Thanks.

Comment: I know this is old but in case someone else finds this through a web search like I did, UniformGrid may be a quicker option (I don't know about performances and extensibility though). https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.controls.primitives.uniformgrid

Answer (score 2, accepted):

New solution/workaround. The UserControl can stay as it is, we'll leave the scaling to the parent container.

We can't accomplish Min(Width, Height) with just the UserControl because if we set the Height for it, then the parent container won't scale it Verticaly and the same goes for Width. If we try to juggle them around then there are situations where we end in an endless Width/Height resizing loop.

What we need is another hidden control in the same space that fills it completely and can tell us what its Width and Height is everytime it changes. Then we can use the Math.Min(Width, Height) solution. Something like this. Notice how both controls are in Grid.Row="1" and Grid.Column="1".

```
<Rectangle Name="availableSpace"
           SizeChanged="availableSpace_SizeChanged"
           Fill="Transparent"
           Grid.Row="1"
           Grid.Column="1"/>
<myLib:UserControl1 x:Name="userControl11"
                    Grid.Row="1"
                    Grid.Column="1"
                    HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                    VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
```

And then in the availableSpace_SizeChanged EventHandler

```
private void availableSpace_SizeChanged(object sender, SizeChangedEventArgs e)
{
    double minValue = Math.Min(availableSpace.ActualWidth, availableSpace.ActualHeight);
    userControl1.Width = minValue;
    userControl1.Height = minValue;
}
```

Now we have 1:1 ratio of the UserControl and it will scale both Vertically and Horizontally

Comment: The first answer worked well, except for I need both the Width and the Height to be Math.Min(Width, Height). How would that be implemented?

Comment: Not sure I understand what you mean, Height will always be equal to ActualWidth. What is the Min value in Math.Min(Width, Height)? Some other value or the Width/Height of your control?

Comment: Umm... I want With and Height to be 1:1. And if the control is in a window that is 500x300 (Width x Height) then my control will, by default, become 500x300. Then my SizeChanged event fires and the control will become 500x500. Now it's height is going out of the window. Instead, I want the control to become 300x300 (Math.Min(500, 300) = 300).

Comment: This is exactly how I ended up doing it.

Answer (score 2):

I think the simplest solution is to set the size of your `UserControl` to some constant value where `Height == Width`, and then drop the whole thing in a `Viewbox` which will handle the scaling (whilst maintaining aspect ratio) for you:

```
<Viewbox>
    <myLib:UserControl1 x:Name="userControl11" />
</Viewbox>
```

This does mean that your control will be *'stretched'* rather than being resized, which might make it inappropriate for you, but it is easy to implement!